# What are the advantages of implementing a generic interface with constraints?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a Generic Interface that defines methods for mapping Type `T` to type `U`. The interface is defined like this:

```
    public interface IDataMapper<T, U>
    {
         U Map(T toMap);
    }
```

What would be the advantage of implementing this interface using a constraint for `T` and `U` instead of directly specifying the types. For example, using this:

```
    public class AuditFileMapper<T, U> : IDataMapper<T, U> where T : Audit where U : File
    {
        public virtual U Map(T toMap)
        {
            //Implementation details here.
        }
    }
```

Instead of this:

```
public class AuditFileMapper : IDataMapper<Audit, File>
```

One advantage I can think of is that if you inherit from `AuditFileMapper` you can change the type in the child with a child of `Audit` or `File` without having to cast the types to the corresponding subclass. Are there more advantages? For example:

```
public class ExtendedAuditFile : AuditFileMapper<ExtendedAudit, XMLFile>
{
     public override XMLFile Map(ExtendedAudit toMap)
     {
          base.Map(toMap);
          //Implementation details here.
     }
}
```

Where `ExtendedAudit` is a child of `Audit` and `XMLFile` is a child of `File`.

Comment: If you think you'll have some reason to parameterize the types handled by `AuditFileMapper`, parameterize them. If you don't... don't. This is actually a powerful general rule in meany realms: If you'll need A, do A. Otherwise, don't.

Comment: In my actual code I don't need the parameterization, but I got curious about when would the constraints be usefull aside from saving you the need to cast the parameter in the child clases.

Comment: It's preferable as a rule to avoid casts (unless you'd have to do something crazy to avoid them -- not the case here). Your `ExtendedAuditFile` is a fine example. The constrained type parameters make it possible for the compiler to communicate to the consumer of your class exactly what's allowed and what isn't, and enforce it. The alternative is the consumer having to read documentation, which programmers resist doing. Less hassle for everybody this way.